# Retrieve all files from current directory and sub-directories

Tags: php, file

I am trying to use the following function to retrieve all files in the folder and subfolder, not sure why it returns no result.

```
function listDirectory($path){
    $ret = array();
    function listFolderFiles($dir){
        global $ret;
        if (is_dir($dir) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        $ffs = scandir($dir);
        unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
        unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

        foreach($ffs as $ff){
            $ret[] = $ff;
            if(is_dir($ff)) {
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    listFolderFiles($path);
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: `$ret = array(); return $ret` : Is there a reason why you need this variable on this `method`?

Comment: Good point, I will change my code in a sec, basically, $ret variable will be the array that will hold all files and this needs to be returned by the function. Please look at the updated code

Answer (score 0):

It returns `null` because the execution of code stops in here

```
if (count($ffs) < 1) {
    return;
}
```

This is mainly because you've might place a given `$path` value might be an empty [directory] meaning, no [files] or [directories] at all.

Your method `listDirectory` will return an `array` if the `$path` given is actually a directory that contains either a `file` or `directory`.

If you want, You can add another validation before you've called the `scandir` method first.

```
function listFolderFiles($dir) {
    global $ret;
    if (is_dir($dir) !== true) {
        return false;
    }

    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    // Rest of code
}
```

Hope this helps for your case.

Comment: Thank you very much eeya, I changed my code but still not working, please look at the updated code.

Comment: What `result` did you've get when you debug that method? `var_dump(listDirectory($path)); exit;`

Comment: Array of fall files and folders in the directory array(758)

Comment: If you can retrieve the files and folders you've needed, There is no problem. How do you call this method `listDirectory` anyway?

Comment: listDirectory("../../../../wp-content/uploads/");

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help, sorted.

```
var_dump(listDirectory("../../../../wp-content/uploads/"));exit;
function listDirectory($path){
    //var_dump($path);exit;
    if(!file_exists ( $path)) {
        var_dump("File doesn't exist");exit;
    }
    $ret = array();
    function listFolderFiles($dir){
        global $ret;
        if (is_dir($dir) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        $ffs = scandir($dir);
        unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
        unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);
        foreach($ffs as $ff){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
                listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            } else {
                $ret[] = $ff;
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    return listFolderFiles($path);
}
```